# Restore "Continuous" form behavior in MS Access after subform is added

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I created an *Organization* form in Access 2007 that could be used to display any record in the *Organization* table by clicking the navigation buttons that appear at the bottom of the form when it is in "Form View". Next, I created a subform within the Organization form to display records from another table that have a foreign key from the Organization table.

Now the "Default View" property of the Organization form has been automatically set to "Single Form" and when I try to set it to "Continuous Forms" I get the following message:

> **You can't view a form as a continuous form if it contains a subform, an ActiveX control, or a bound chart.**
>
> Set the DefaultView property of the form to Single Form, Datasheet,
>   PivotTable, or PivotChart.

Furthermore, I am unable to use the form to view any records other than the first record in the Organization table. How can display other records from the Organization table in my form using record IDs?

Comment: When I do this, I can indeed set the form to continuous, but everything in the "Detail" (body) section mysteriously disappears and the record navigation still shows only one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While investigating this problem, I discovered that Microsoft's own [Northwind Traders Sample Database](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19704) contains at least one form with subforms that exhibited the behavior I wanted, even in the "Single Form" view. This suggested that the subform was not the cause of the problem.

In trying to reproduce the affect accomplished in the sample database, I recreated my form and re-added elements too it one-by-one, testing the navigation at each step. I was able to view different records via the "Form View" navigation button until I added controls from a table other than Organization that weren't contained within a subform.

So there you have it; switching between a form's source records via the navigation controls in "Form View" does not work when the master form contains records from more than one table.